# How can I sort elasticsearch/searchkick date field?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have an elastic search index for a date field in `%d-%m-%Y` format as strings.

I'm using Searchkick and I have no issues if I want to sort by string.

```
User.search("*", {oder: {"name" => :asc}})
```

However if try with a date field it wont do the sorting properly, as for example:

```
User.search("*", {oder: {"created_at" => :asc}})
```

Any help?

Comment: Field "created_at" need to be date type, not string in order to make right sorting.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html

Comment: Thanks for the help Andriy. I know it would work if the field is a date field, just thought there would be some work around for string type like to specify the date format.

Answer (score 2):

```
User.search("*", order: {created_at: :asc})
```

should work